# Modal Popup Extender panel height width

Tags: asp.net, size, panel

I have a ajax asp.net modalpopupextender, I wont when I desplay popup,  the popup cover all the browser window.

The popup display a panel one is inside the form not other container.

My .aspx code is:
< asp:Panel ID="OptionPanel" runat="server" CssClass="mp"
        Style="display: block; width:100%; height:100%">

But don't work!!!

Any ideas????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModalPopupExtender's main Panel should not have block display style, it [must be hidden](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx):

> The ModalPopupExtender that this popup
>   is attached to has a hidden
>   TargetControl.

E.g. `Style="display: hidden;"`

The size of Panel (div) can be resized with JS, for example.